# Azure Functions ncrontab value

Tags: cron, azure-functions

I just want you guys to double check to see if I'm getting this `ncrontab` expression right for my Azure Function.

I'd like my function to run:

- Monday through Friday
- Every 30 minutes starting at the top of the hour
- Starting at 9 AM
- Ending at 6 PM

As I understand it, there are six places in `ncrontab` Azure Functions use.

They are: `{second} {minute} {hour} {day} {month} {dayOfWeek}`.

Here's what I've come up with:
`0 */30 9-18 * * 1-5`

Is my expression correct? A related question is do these values need to be UTC times?

Here's the documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the expression is correct.

For the questions about UTC times, The `default time zone` used with the CRON expressions is `UTC`. And you can change the time zone by creating `an app setting` for your function app named `WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE`. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp#ncrontab-time-zones) for more details.